# How does this javascript get called within asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

New admin to asp.net c# solution.  Trying to reverse engineer exactly how as subsequent .js file is being used /called.

Within the project directory i have a ~/Sripts/jstree.js script.

I know the default page loads it, i can see from the client side when using debug tools for a browser.  I just don't know how to make the leap from the aspx, the aspx.cs to how it then calls jstree.js?

The default aspx page that loads for the user contains the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Organizations.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutismPro.Classroom.Administration.Organizations" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Admin.Master" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Assembly="VirtualExpertClinics.Web" Namespace="VirtualExpertClinics.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc2" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="stylesPlaceHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="stylesContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/jstree") %>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="scriptsPlaceHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptsContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jstree") %>
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pages/administration/organizations") %>
```

followed by:

```
<asp:Content ID="leftContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <h2 class="pageTitle"><%: Resources.Global.Organizations %></h2>
    <div class="contentBox">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Search %>" OnClientClick="searchOrganizations(); return false;" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="hideInactiveCheckBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, HideInactive %>" Checked="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
        <div id="organizationsTree" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

My question is, what is being called from "**organizationsTree**", and then how is that being loaded.

I can see the c# code behind the aspx page Page_Loads:

```
       // set jsTree data URL
            organizationsTree.Attributes["data-url"]
                = ResolveUrl("~/Administration/Organizations.aspx/GetOrganizationTreeData");
```

**organizationsTree**  attribute "data-url" is defined by a function within the C# page **GetOrganizationTreeData**  and per the comment it sets the javascript data url for **jsTree**

Without posting all the code, I'm hoping you guys could help me understand how **jsTree.js** is being called.

Starting with the aspx snippet above.  Is it the "stylePlaceHolder" ~/Content/jstree"?

I don't have a folder in my project called ~/Content/jstree?

Any insights or tips and tricks from the browser side even would be appreciated....

I've tried placing a breakpoint on jstree.js and stepping through my code, but I don't ever see it called (not sure js debugging works the same in VS as it does with c#?)

There is no reference in the aspx or the aspx.cs file for jstree.js

Thx in advance,

Comment: It seems to me, organizationsTree on the serverside code is a UserControl with its own rendering code or am I wrong. Probably there html get's composed that uses jsTree on the client to enable the tree functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's is done by [bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), specifically this line of code:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jstree") %>
```

This represents 1 or more javascript files for jstree, whatever is defined in your code base.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply.  Got it, makes sense.  I see bundle.config now and see it registers my ~/scripts

Thank you very much